# how to display data point names outside of pie chart in ssrs 2008?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I created Pie report in SSRS 2008 R2.
My Problem is want to display data in outside
Can anyone give me the steps How to display Names in outside of report

Answer (score 4):

Go to the **Chart Series** Properties by either clicking on the chart labels or the data field in the Designer.

Change **Label** -> **Position** from *Auto*:

[image]

to *Outside*:

[image]

Chart with *Auto* position:

[image]

Chart with *Outside* position:

[image]

Obviously you'll need to work with the chart/label size to get the Chart looking OK, but hopefully this gets you on the right path.

**Edit after comment:**

You can set the labels as required under **Series Label Properties** -> **General** -> **Label data**:

[image]

Set it to something like:

```
=Fields!YourField.Value & " " & CStr(Count(Fields!YourField.Value))
```

as required. Obviously you haven't supplied any details of your DataSet so you'll need to update to suit your requirements.

Comment: Hi Ian Thnks for your reply,how can i display Names with values(besides) in the above report,plz explain me

Comment: I've added a brief update based on your comment. Please note this is an entirely separate issue to your original question so if you need more information you should ask a new question with the relevant information. If the original issue, i.e. the position of data labels, has been resolved, please consider marking as accepted/upvoting.

Comment: This was extremely helpful! It seems I needed to set the outside value in two places. Thanks for this Ian!

Comment: Great! If an answer helps you, please considering setting it as the accepted answer... It helps future readers understand that this could help them with similar issues.